# Attribute modifiers in inventory

Tags: minecraft-commands

How do I make items give you attributes when they are in the inventory? It only works when the player holds the item or wears it, but not when the item is in the inventory.

Comment: Lets see... there´s "when on (armour slot)", "when in main hand", "when in off hand", idk about in inventory

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It's impossible.

Attributes are only applied when the item is "active", meaning it is in any of the following slots:

- helmet slot
- chestplate slot
- leggings slot
- boots slot
- offhand slot
- selected hotbar slot

And even there they have to be the item itself, not its content (for example an item which gives attributes doesn't work if you hold a shulker box containing it).